# Determining which listboxitem is clicked on in a listbox when executing a context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, contextmenu

I am trying to use context menu in a listbox to run some come code.that require data from which item it originated.the click event context menu item shows msg but i found that it doent not access the originating listview item .

```
<Canvas x:Name="LeftCanvas"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,0,0">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Unseated Guests" Background="Blue" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Height="17" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center"  Padding="0,4,5,2"></TextBlock>
        <ListBox x:Name="UnseatedPersons" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="218"  Width="150" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="3,2,2,2" src:FloorPlanClass.DragEnabled="true" MouseEnter="UnseatedPersons_MouseEnter"
             MouseLeave="SourceListBox_MouseLeave">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Archive Info" Click="bt_click" />
                                    <MenuItem Header="Guest Info" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <Image Name="imgPerson" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                            <TextBlock Name="txtPersonName" Text="{Binding PersonName}" Padding="2,4,0,0" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>            
</Canvas>
```

C#:

```
void bt_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("my message");
}
```

Comment: You have asked 9 questions so far and not accepted a single answer. Please accept some answers. Also your code is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Use the sender by casting them to `MenuItem`. Like:

```
void bt_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MenuItem originalItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("clicked from \"{0}\"", originalItem.Name)); 
}
```

Comment: i want to get on which listbox itm u clicked

Comment: @user: if they are not `MenuItem` then cast to `ListBoxItem` instead So: `ListBoxItem originalItem = (ListBoxItem)sender;` Here you are getting the listbox item that clicked.

Answer (score 1):

1. The sender in the click event will be the `MenuItem` you clicked.
2. Its parent will be the `ContextMenu`
3. The `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu` will be the `DockPanel`.
4. The `DockPanel` will have the `ListBoxItem` as an ancestor in the Visual Tree

So to get the `ListBoxItem` in the click event you can use something similar to this

```
private void bt_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem clickedMenuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    ContextMenu contextMenu = clickedMenuItem.Parent as ContextMenu;
    DockPanel dockPanel = contextMenu.PlacementTarget as DockPanel;
    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = GetVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(dockPanel);
    MessageBox.Show(listBoxItem.ToString());

    // Update. To display the content of the ListBoxItem
    MessageBox.Show(listBoxItem.Content.ToString());
}

public static T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;
    // iteratively traverse the visual tree
    while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
    return child as T;
}
```

Comment: it displays only system.data.datarowview

Comment: @user644194: The MessageBox was just an example, if you're getting datarowview in there then it seems that you succesfully got the ListBoxItem, or did I missunderstand something?

Comment: @user644194: Updated my answer, was this what you were looking for?